# How to overwrite the hashcode method that returns a unique hashcode value with its unique entity ID in my defined Java object?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, compare, hashcode

I faced a case of using a complex Map which uses my defined Java object as its key, to do this  the class of this object need to implement interface Comparable and overwrite Object's hashcode and equals methods, and I want to use unique ID of object of this class as it hashcode, but the unique ID is Long type and the type of value hashcode returns is Integer, this may suffer from data corruption and inconsistency if ID of object increased to a very large one.

Is there any way to convert a unique long-type ID to a hashcode that can also be used to identify between objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to rely on `java.lang.Long`'s built-in `hashCode()`:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Long.valueOf(getId()).hashCode();
}
```

Edit:
As per the comment below, if the id is stored as a `java.lang.Long` and not a primitive `long`, it's even simpler:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getId().hashCode();
}
```

Comment: There may be a slight performance issue with this approach - `valueOf()` typically creates a new object. The JVM will probably create it on the stack, but I am not sure if it is smart enough to avoid creating it entrirely.

Comment: Hehe, Actually in my circumstance I don't even need to create a new Long instance since it is already existed in my object, I just need to do it in hashcode method: return this.getId().hashcode();

Comment: @BradyChu: well, in that case it does not matter :-) But if you are wondering, a little JMH benchmark shows that the `valueOf()` approach is about 3 times slower than the `Long.hashCode(long)` static method on Java 8. Depending on the application, that might actually be important...

Answer (score 0):

you can call hashcode method of Long simply

for example :

new Long(4).hashCode();

Answer (score 0):

The most common way that the main Java libraries convert a `long` to an `int` for the `hashCode()` method is with a couple of bitwise operations:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (int)(value ^ (value >>> 32));
}
```

Incindentally, in Java 8 there is a [`Long.hashCode(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) static method that does just that:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Long.hashCode(value);
}
```

Please note that this process is *not* reversible - there isn't a one-to-one mapping from `long` values to their hash code, due to the differing ranges.